# How to open nested div with href

Tags: jquery, html

I want to open nested div on a `href` click -

```
  <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
  <a href="#inside" id="touchstartcss">School News</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="basePage">
  <div data-role="page" id="inside" >
  </div>
  </div>
```

but the `inside` div is not opening.

Comment: Where is the `#inside` div?

Comment: my `inside` div is inside `basePage` and I am using jquery for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Try

jQuery

```
$('#touchstartcss').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   $('#inside').show();
});
```

Css

```
#inside{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('#touchstartcss').click(function(){
    $(this.href).show();
})
```